# Weird OGNL error on RedHat only: works correctly everywhere but production

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2, redhat

I have a block of code that's doing very standard CRUD operations in a Struts2/Spring/Hibernate/Tomcat app.

The problem is that *only on our production server* I get the following stack trace. It works great on my 64-bit Mac, and on a 32-bit Ubuntu in a VM. I only get the error on this RedHat 4.1.2 server:

```
ERROR InstantiatingNullHandler: Could not create and/or set value back on to object
ognl.NoSuchPropertyException: com.martin.action.assignment.SaveAssignment.course 

[java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class ognl.OgnlRuntime can not access a member 
of class com.martin.action.assignment.EditAssignment with modifiers "protected"]
```

I've tried using JRockit on the RedHat server instead of Oracle JDK... same error.

What on earth could be causing this issue?

BTW: the OGNL jar is ognl-2.6.11

Comment: You have some `protected` member of `com.martin.action.assignment.EditAssignment` class. Try to change it to `public`.

Comment: Thanks, but why would that only throw an exception on RedHat Linux?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading OGNL to 3.0.x ? Unless you are using a very old version of Struts2 (2.0?), it is the right choice. Try, and see if you get the same error. +1 btw...